# how to use reserved words in an access database with dapper in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2015, dapper

how to use reserved words in an access database with dapper in VB.NET?
I want to use "name" if there is a solution without changing the name in the field in the access database.

Thanks

```
              Con.Execute($"Update Users Set name = name,email = @email,phone = @phone,password = @password Where id = @id", New With {
                    Key .name = bunifuTextBox1.Text,
                    Key .email = txtEmail.Text,
                    Key .phone = bunifuTextBox2.Text,
                    Key .password = txtPassword.Text,
                    Key .id = id
                })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use brackets:

```
Con.Execute($"Update Users Set [name] = @name, email = @email, phone = @phone, [password] = @password Where id = @id", ...
```

Comment: thanks answer from you went perfectly